# How to remove space on the sides and bottom of footer

Tags: html, css, responsive, footer

I made a footer but I can't remove the space on the left, right and bottom.

HTML

```
<footer id="footerID" class="footer">
      <a
        href="https://www.linkedin.com/home?originalSubdomain=pt"
        target="_blank"
        >LinkedIn</a
      >
      <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
      <a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #64ffc6;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .footer > a{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#182436;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/alexkoyomi/pen/GRdKPRw?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

The body element has default margin. Remove it like this :

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```